# How to limit Bing Search API V5 to search specific sections of the website

Tags: bing, bing-api, bing-search, azure-cognitive-services

Using bing.com, I can do a search like this (click [here](https://www.bing.com/search?q=history+site%3Aberkeley.edu%2Fabout%2F&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=undefined&sc=0-32&sk=&cvid=17ED4EFA4ED24E36B89F1B67F2F8EAF3) for link):

```
history site:berkeley.edu/about/
```

When I try the same using the API, I get very different results. As far as I can tell, the search results returns webpages that are not hosted in berkeley.edu (see bottom).

this is the HTTP GET request being made to Azure

```
https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/search?q=history+site:berkeley.edu/about/&count=10&offset=0
```

This is my HTTP GET code

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/search"
        , data: { "q":encodeURI("history+site:berkeley.edu/about/"), "count":"10", "offset":"0" }
        , beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","supply-your-key-here");
        }
        , type: "GET",
    })
```

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong? Thanks

**edit1:** Seems my "problem" is related to the way AJAX is making the HTTP request. If I supply my key by using a Firefox header plugin and type this (https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/search?q=history+site:berkeley.edu/about/&count=10&offset=0) on my browser URL box, I get the correct response.

search results using API

```
    Environmental Design Library | UC Berkeley Library: A branch of the UC Berkeley Library system, the Environmental Design Library supports the research and teaching of the College of Environmental Design.

Proceedings Template - WORD - ideals.illinois.edu: "(c) ACM, 2007. This is the authors’ version of the work. It is posted here by permission of ACM for your personal use. Not for redistribution.

Trends in metadata practices: A longitudinal study of ...: Trends in metadata practices: A longitudinal study of collection federation. ... A Longitudinal Study of Collection Federation Carole Palmer Oksana ...

http://aerospaceutility.tripod.com/ · GitHub: Clone via HTTPS Clone with Git or checkout with SVN using the repository's web address.

HS RWC Colorado Sample Instructional Units - LiveBinder: Loading Livebinder HS RWC Colorado Sample Instructional Units HS Read Write Communicate Sample Instructional Units provided by the Colorado Department of Education.

Arroyo High School: News Archive: News Archive SIA Awards "As the school year comes to a close, the Students in Action club would like to honor three students for their lasting impact on our ...

English 12 (exp) | Utah Electronic High School: Please be mindful of the fact that this course is not a credit "quick fix." It is a rigorous, college-preparatory class that is both time and labor intensive.

Working SMARTer, not Harder: SOCIAL STUDIES ONLINE ...: SOCIAL STUDIES ONLINE RESOURCES AND LINKS COMPILATION beta List of Social Studies online resources and links to professional development opportunities ...

The Big List -- 20121008 - Grolier: The Big List -- 20121008: 1: EA: http://www.stanford.edu/group/bipolar.clinic/ Stanford Bipolar Disorders Clinic: 2: EA: http://www.mhsource.com/bipolar/

Spreadsheet of Conference Attendees - studylib.net: ÐÏ à¡± á > þÿ ] þÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Bing custom search alternately to make sure you get results only from the domain/webpages you want. Here is the call: https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bingcustomsearch/v7.0/search. You will need a different accesskey though, which you can get from customsearch.ai.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting correct results on both v5.0 and v7.0.
There seems nothing wrong with your query.

```
https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/search?q=history+site:berkeley.edu/about/&count=10&offset=0
```

Perhaps you are caching results somewhere in your browser?

**Update**: Since IE does it, but Firefox doesn't. Have you disabled cache on IE?